# Functions that are Khinchin integrable but not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, gauge-integral

I have read that the [Khinchin integral](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Khinchin_integral) is more general than the Henstock-Kurzweil integral ([gauge integral](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Herschlag.pdf)). I am studying gauge integration for a course right now and am not quite at the level to answer this question, but while I'm getting there, I'd like to ask:

> What are some Khinchin integrable $f$ which are not Henstock-Kurzweil integrable?

(Aside: this *is* a sensible question, correct? There *are* such functions, otherwise nobody would bother to distinguish the Khinchin integral from the less general case of the Henstock-Kurzweil integral, correct?)

Comment: Cross-posted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350830/functions-that-are-khinchin-integrable-but-not-henstock-kurzweil-integrable